# Given a heap of abilities (damage&cooldown) find the optimal set of 8 abilities

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-modeling

Let's call an ability a pair of two integer numbers: *damage* and *cooldown*. We have a bunch ($\ge 8$) of abilities. We must find a set of 8 abilities from that bunch so that average damage per turn will be maximum.

Note that every ability can be used once every $\mathcal N$ turns, where $\mathcal N$ is the cooldown of this ability. Only one ability could be used per turn

**If there is a good computing algorithm to solve this problem? Is there some areas of math I should look into to find a clue?**

I think the central part of the problem is to find an algorythm to find the best accomodation so that abilities in the set will conflict as little as possible

Comment: I suppose cooldown depends on ability. Store damage per turn for 8 best abilities (i.e. during the pass on all abilities). This requires exactly one pass and is called greedy algorithm. Since the only requirement is to have max average damage per turn, this is also optimal

Comment: @dEmigOd Assuming you choose the abilities with highest damage per turn, you only achieve that damage if it is possible to use every ability immediately when its cooldown is off. I think there may be some cases where it would be better to choose an ability with slightly less damage/cooldown, if it allows you to have less conflict in the order you use the abilities. Would you have any ideas on how to deal with this, or maybe why it is not relevant ?

Comment: There could be many constraints. They are not currently stated. I've tried to solve the stated problem as is. As is, it seems to me things are pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @dEmigOd N.Bach is right, I want to find the maximum value of limit for damage divided by the number of turns as number of turns tends to infinity

Comment: In other words, let n be a number of turns spent using the strategy. I want to find the set of 8 abilities, which will allow for a strategy so that limit for damage dealt divided by n as n tends to infinity will be maximum

Comment: Well technically dEmigOd is right, in its current formulation your problem is missing the assumption that you can use at most one ability per turn, so his solution works for what you described. You should probably edit your question.

Comment: @N.Bach done, thank you

Comment: Your first step is dangerous as you can't tell if the Damage: 4000 | Cooldown: 5 is in fact any worst to use than the damage: 100 | Cooldown: 4, the fact that another ability with the same cooldown is better does not mean that that ability could not be the second best out of all abilities to use.

Comment: @SonnyDaSilva-Peters Makes sense. I think you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like an NP-hard problem to me like the knapsack problem.  It seems unlikely there is a simple algorithm that handles all the cases if you have a huge pile of abilities to choose from with funny numbers of damage and cooldown.  On the other hand, with a reasonably sized pile you can just try all the cases and often many of them will be obviously bad.

Even in the long term case you can't just compute the damage per round for each ability.  If you have one that does a lot of damage rarely you are encouraged to choose others that recharge more quickly.  Another approach is to have a lot of abilities that all cool down in 8 so you cycle through them.  There will probably be a small number of cases to check.

Startup effects can play a role as well.  Say you have one with damage of 100 and cooldown 1000.  You can only use it once if the battles last less than 1000, but maybe it blows most things away on the first shot.  If you can space your battles out enough that it cools down you don't need any others.